# Field day questions

Tags: discussion, topic-of-the-week

Let's try and ask as many questions relating to Field Day while they are fresh in our minds. If we do this, then we will have a great list for next year, and as a bonus, we'll also remember the answers when we go to review them for next year. So let's see how many field day questions we can ask/ answer for the next few weeks!

Answer (score 1):

I made a list of possible questions while I was operating, and I've now posted all the ones that seemed worth it after consideration.

- [How many independent power settings does the Yaesu FT-897/857 have?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5046/how-many-independent-power-settings-does-the-yaesu-ft-897-857-have)
- [Is there a convention for SSB frequency selection?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/is-there-a-convention-for-ssb-channel-spacing)
- [Are amateur radio call signs unique among all radio call signs?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5061/are-amateur-radio-call-signs-unique-among-all-radio-call-signs)
- [What are the relative bandwidths of the amateur bands?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/what-are-the-relative-bandwidths-of-the-amateur-bands)
- [Will measuring SWR through a feed line mislead me?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/5098/76)
- [Does a low amount of atmospheric noise reliably indicate a lack of propagation?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/does-a-low-amount-of-atmospheric-noise-reliably-indicate-a-lack-of-propagation)

Comment: Nice start! I've added a few as well.